# Why my Geoserver on JBOSS/RHEL is slower than on Tomcat/Windows?

Tags: geoserver, wms, performance, tomcat, jboss

I have my Geoservers in 2 different environments: Tomcat on Windows and JBOSS on RHEL. I was guessing that JBOSS on RHEL will be faster, but to make sure I made some test plans with JMeter.

Both:

- are VMware servers
- have same number of processor and same amount of memory
- are using exactly same SHP file on each disk (no database)
- are on the same network segment, so network distance to my JMeter (on my Workstation PC) are the same
- are dealing with similar WMS requests and style from my JMeter

My observation shows that Geoserver on JBOSS/RHEL is noticeably slower than on Tomcat/Windows. This brought me to early conclusion that this is because the JBOSS/RHEL is not optimally configured.

But to be sure I made another test with both, but instead of using Geoserver, now only with static content (simply file) with format similar to Geoserver response:

- 8-bit and 32-bit 256x256 PNG
- GML file
- geojson file

Those static content are hosted on both JBOSS/RHEL and Tomcat/Windows. Interestingly now JBOSS/RHEL is faster than Tomcat/Windows.

I returned to the Geoserver test plan an played with Image Processing and Image Encoding options (image below) in Geoserver JBOSS/RHEL.

[image]

This is because I suspected the java/image processing is the source of problem. But the result is the same: Geoserver on JBOSS/RHEL is slower.

The speed difference of the two Geoserver is not only measured in JMeter, but even visually noticeable in OpenLayers(!).

Here is the summary of the 2 servers (server #20 vs #21):
[image]

Now the suspect is clear: the Geoserver on my JBOSS is not working optimal.

Where do i start to try and fix this?

---

ADDED INFOS:
Java version is added in the above comparison.

I checked [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/) as suggested by @bugmenot. I think the most relevant item is the JVM Optimization in the [Container Considerations](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/container.html). The link suggests to set several JVM parameters (1-7 in the table below). Another [site](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/enterprise/jvm.html) suggests few other parameter (8-11).

Therefore i checked  both server:

[image]

The JVM parameter in JBOSS does not differ too much with Tomcat.

But still, I tried to increase (in JBOSS server #21) the InitialHeapSize to 128MB and MaxHeapSize to 2048MB, with the following command:

```
java -Xms128m -Xmx2048m -version
```

No error. But when i check with the command:

```
java -Xms128m -Xmx756m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'InitialHeapSize|MaxHeapSize'
```

Both heap size doesn't change to the value I wanted.

So my question now:

1. Both server doesn't differ too much. So why?
2. Does Java version affects ?
3. How to set JVM memory amount (eg. increase heap size) for
   JBOSS?

---

Below are images showing the test plans.

[image: Summary Report]
The above shows Summary Report of Geoserver test plan: JBOSS is slower than Tomcat.

[image]
The above shows Response Time of Geoserver test plan: JBOSS is slower than Tomcat.

[image]
The above shows Summary Report of Static Content (no Geoserver) test plan: JBOSS is faster than Tomcat.

[image]
The above shows Response Time of Static Content (no Geoserver) test plan: JBOSS is faster than Tomcat.

Comment: are you using the same JVM on each?

Comment: Did you follow http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/ ?

Comment: @iant. I added java version in the comparison.

Comment: @bugmenot I checked that . I added more infos in the question accordingly.

Comment: Which version of geoserver are you using?

Comment: @iant. The GeoServers are different. GeoServer 2.7.0 on Tomcat/Windows and GeoServer 2.10.1 on JBOSS/RHEL. This is described already in the comparison table (image) in my question above.

Comment: Well using the same one on each machine is probably a first step

Comment: @iant. Oh and one more thing: GeoServer 2.7.0 on Tomcat/Windows has Native JAI set to FALSE and GeoServer 2.10.1 on JBOSS/RHEL has Native JAI set to TRUE.

Comment: Just adding more relevant info with regards to performance: Andrea Aime said _most of the time performance issues are not related to lack of native JAI, but to bad data preparation_ in [this forum](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/How-to-enable-or-disable-the-Native-JAI-in-Geoserver-2-5-2-td5157219.html). But in my case both servers are using exactly the same SHP stored locally in each disk. I guess data prep is vital but apparently infras and tuning count as well. (Tuning in JBOSS/RHEL that is still beyond my knowledge)